# Bootstrap show many slides one carousel - animation gap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's Show Many Slide one Carousel (https://github.com/rtpHarry/Bootstrap3-ShowManySlideOneCarousel) inside a large dropdown; that's working fine. But the issue of animation gap / items overlap issue is being seen.

Here is the screenshot for that issue: https://ibb.co/ikztJ5

I raised this issue in github as well: https://github.com/rtpHarry/Bootstrap3-ShowManySlideOneCarousel/issues/4 , but no response yet.

I am using the same code as given in the repository.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: did you add the class "img-responsive" in image

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: Share your wrking code

Comment: I got to resolve the issue, it was a small width issue, I was giving extra padding and margin for the carousel-indicators, which was causing flicker issue, https://jsfiddle.net/aningbo/a5zLhjmr/ , this link helped me solve that issue.